# Insert HTML after element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

I'm looking to add a button after a specific element on an existing page. This is the code I've tried so far.

```js
$('.collection-nav').after('<span class="button">This is a button.</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="index-navigation collection-nav" role="navigation">


  <div class="collection-nav-item" data-url-id="process">
    <a href="/process/" class="process">
      <span class="collection-nav-item-span">Process</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="collection-nav-item" data-url-id="our-breads">
    <a href="/our-breads/" class="our-breads">
      <span class="collection-nav-item-span">Bread</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="collection-nav-item" data-url-id="ourculutre">
    <a href="/ourculutre/" class="ourculutre">
      <span class="collection-nav-item-span">Culture</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="collection-nav-item" data-url-id="about">
    <a href="/about/" class="about">
      <span class="collection-nav-item-span">About</span>
    </a>
  </div>


</nav>
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Seems to work fine. (And don't use `<span class="button">`, HTML has a perfectly good `<button>` element.)

Comment: by "after" i assume you meant inside and first before all of it's existing children? because that's not what `after` is for.

Comment: Do you mean `.append()` ? You want to add it at the last inside `<nav>` container?

Comment: @KevinB The button needs to go after the </nav> tag.

Comment: Then your code works as written.

Comment: @KevinB Weird because it's not working on the site I've added it to the header of.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe this has something to do with it being a Squarespace site and they are blocking the injection somehow.

Comment: my guess is you’re running the code before the element you are targeting exists on the page.

Comment: @KevinB Hmm good guess. Let me try putting it into the footer and seeing if that works.

Comment: @KevinB That worked!

Answer (score -1):

as far as I can see, the code you wrote is correct, but it needs to be triggered to work.

you can add a button like this => `<button id="btnAfter">After Element</button>`

you can try again later your code:

```
$('#btnAfter').click(function(){
  $('.collection-nav').after('<span class="button">This is a button.</span>');
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require clicking a button to inject the button? This button needs to be added after the </nav> tag upon the page load.

Comment: I don't think the location of the button is important. At the beginning or end does not change the result.